# Javascript - combine variables to form path

Tags: javascript

I need to combine two variables and one static string to form a path to may image - see below. Please advise on how to correct the syntax:

```
var shortUrl = "http://www.art.com";
album_name = "art";

poster:""+shortUrl+""/""+album_name+"".jpg",
```

I am trying to get it to output:
http://www.art.com/art.jpg

Comment: var poster = shortUrl + "/" + album_name + ".jpg";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
shortUrl + "/" + album_name + ".jpg";
```

You don't need to escape slashes when they are inside a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `var` to prevent the variables from becoming global, assign the result to `poster` with an `=`, remove the opening `""`, and only use one `"` on either side of a string.

```
var shortUrl = "http://www.art.com";
var album_name = "art";

var poster = shortUrl +"/" + album_name + ".jpg";

console.log(poster);
```